# selenium <element is not attached to the page document" in selenium> Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i'm trying to get data instantly from active element using Xpath
but when i run the project i got this error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: **element is not attached to the page document**

```
    package read;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    public class ResdeStoFromBrowser {
    
        public static final String TEXT_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
        public static final String TEXT_RED = "\u001B[31m";
        public static final String TEXT_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
        public static final String TEXT_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    
        public void ResdeSto() throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\owner\\....\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("https:.........");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            while (true) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                String sel2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]")).getText();
                System.out.println(TEXT_GREEN + "  " + sel2 + TEXT_RESET + "    ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have an endless loop at the end?

Comment: To keep getting data endlessly from the source !!

Comment: That makes no sense and it could be a problem.

Comment: Can u pls add HTML code or the URL

Comment: @Sonali Adding HTML to the post will not help because page contents changes.

Comment: @hfontanez How do you then identify the XPath of other elements if the page content changes

Comment: @hfontanez  how to get data endlessly and Secondly (s) or (ms) from URL

Comment: @DAROUYABDELKARIM let me know if you do not understand what I posted in my answer.

Comment: @DAROUYABDELKARIM the code I wrote should work in an infinite loop, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: @hfontanez id id not assume that xpath is the problem. I asked it because to reproduce the issue  I would need either the HTML code or the URL. then only I can answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "*I'm trying to get data instantly*..." Well, this could be a problem.

`StaleElementReferenceException` are thrown when a web element is obtained before the contents of the webpage refreshes or during the refresh process. In other words, it is obtained prematurely. The solution is to wait until the page finishes loading completely.

"Element is not attached to the page document" means that the web element is probably no longer in the HTML document.

There are two ways of obtaining a web element:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.findElement(...);
```

Assuming that you are on the correct page, *`findElement`* will attempt to locate the element without delay. If the page is in the process of loading, it will most likely result in the error mentioned in the OP's post. The correct way to fix this is to add an implicit wait.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Time amount and time units are arbitrary.
// get to the page...
driver.findElement(...);
```

In the above snippet, from the moment *`implicitlyWait`* is called until the end of the test session, before any attempt to obtain a web element, the application will wait the minimum amount of time passed to the function; in my example that's 10 seconds.

A better way to do this is to use `WebDriverWait` class.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // max. wait time set to 10 seconds with default 500 ms polling interval
```

`WebDriverWait` has a three-argument variant where the third argument is the polling interval in milliseconds. For example, `WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100)` will wait a maximum of 10 seconds, polling every 100 ms. Once the `wait` object is obtained, it will be used to obtain a `WebElement` object passing the correct expected condition provided by the `ExpectedConditions` class. For example, to wait until a button becomes "clickable" (both *visible* and *enabled*)

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(XPATH EXPRESSION HERE)));
button.click();
```

This approach, assuming you are already on the correct page, will attempt to locate the desired component the maximum amount of time passed to the `WebDriverWait` constructor before it times out. But, if the component is located AND the expected condition is reached before timing out, it will return the requested component. This is a better way to avoid stale element (although not completely).

Probably the best approach is to combine both of the approaches.

To start, set the implicit wait time as soon as the web driver instance is obtained

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then, navigate to the page

```
driver.navigate().to("https:.........");
```

Lastly, use the second approach to obtain the web element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("...")));
button.click();
```

When implicit and explicit waits are used together, the chances of stale element issues is reduced to almost zero. You just have to be smart and always obtain the web element just before you are going to use it.... And **DEFINITELY DO NOT** put code like this in an endless loop.

Basically, this code works.... sort of.

```
public class TickerPageTest {
    @Test
    public void printTickerValueEndlessLoop() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Users\\Hector\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://coincheck.com/exchange/tradeview");
        
        while (true) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]")));
        System.out.println(element.getTagName() + ":" + element.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code outputs the following (most of the time)

```
span:5898999
...
span:5900895
...
span:5898999
```

The best bet is to wrap the interaction with the web element in a try/catch where you will catch the `StaleElementReferenceException` to ignore it and continue. In a real Selenium Test, you can you this strategy to retry obtaining the missed element, but in this case you don't need to.

```
try {
    System.out.println(element.getTagName() + ":" + element.getText());
} catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
    System.err.println("Test lost sync... this will be ignored.");
}
```

When I did this, after a few hundred lines (or more) I was able to catch a loss in synchronization:

```
span:5906025
Test lost sync... this will be ignored.
span:5906249
```

But, as you can see, I just ignored it and moved on to the next update.

Comment: @DAROUYABDELKARIM is the URL you're testing public? If so, post the URL.

Comment: i don't know if you can see it in your country [https://coincheck.com/exchange/tradeview]

Comment: @DAROUYABDELKARIM I can see what you're trying to do. BUT, you should understand what I was trying to say: The page is constantly refreshing. This is going to be tricky.

Comment: @DAROUYABDELKARIM my suggested code works for me just fine. I will post.